# Prototype GraphQL, MongoDB -- schema-less?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, graphql

I'm looking into a prototype for a data-heavy application. I have SQL experience, but I am currently in kind-of-love with MongoDB for being schema-less, which for a prototype would be ideal because it allows me to extend the schema during development until everything is right. And I like GraphQL for many reasons, one of them being that I can do a lot of testing and experimenting right on the API without creating a simple UI.

However, as I understand, GraphQL requires a strict schema definition. Which means it doesn't play with MongoDB, at least not while retaining the schema-less attribute.

An absolute requirement is an ability to have backend-processing capabilities. I need to be able to trigger data calculations, so I need some way to write code against the database, ideally in the same framework that's used for the API (of course I could always write some arbitrary DB-centric app, but why should I use two frameworks?)

Is that right or am I misguided? Is there an equivalent of Graphile for MongoDB that allows me to define my schema (which will change often during prototyping) only in one place and have everything updated on-the-fly ? Or am I going down the wrong path at all?

Notes:

- This is not production code. It is prototyping code and requires many iterations with the various stakeholders to get right. That is why I need something that allows rapid development and changes, if possible right then and there to quickly test an alternative approach.
- I need some kind of interface that a non-coder can at least grasp. The GraphQL query language is good enough for that purpose (stakeholders are technical people, but not coders). Pure SQL is questionable, anything beyond that is too much into coding.
- I don't care much for SQL or NoSQL or even Graph DB and neither do I care if it's all written in PHP, Java, NodeJS or something else that I can understand and hack (i.e. not in Brainfuck).

Comment: [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) + [Apollo Server 2](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/getting-started.html) could be good for that. Its not super easy to get used to the multiple schema definition files but all the DB stuff is handled in the cloud.

Comment: [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql#enabling-graphql) - dockerized (multi container), updated on save, react-admin, graphiql, swagger/openapi specs ...

Comment: API platform is indeed on my shortlist.

Comment: I used this with some parts of data serialized to json fields and even as api for  apollo-universal-starter-kit webclient . I think I wouldn't be able to setup (and resolve issues) this faster and easier with node.js (asserts/validations, resolving levels).

Answer (score 0):

```
const { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

const schema = buildSchema(`
type Query {
}

type SchemalessDoc {
    _id: ID!
    json: String!
    get(k:String!): SchemalessDoc!
}

type Mutation {
    # Authentication
    auth(name: String!, phrase: String!): SchemalessDoc!
    deauth: Boolean!

    # CRUD for all models
    create(type:String!, json:String!): SchemalessDoc!
    update(type:String!, _id:ID!, json:String!): SchemalessDoc!
    delete(type:String!, _id:ID!): SchemalessDoc!
}
`);

// NOTICE: the only difference between Query and Mutation is Parallel vs. Serial execution;
//         the labels are more presumptive than prescriptive.

class SchemalessDoc {
    constructor(o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    _id() {
        return this.o._id;
    }

    json() {
        // TODO: could return 'null' but that isn't precise. 'undefined' is invalid JSON, but its no biggie,
        //     just check first: return 'undefined' === s ? undefined : JSON.parse(s);
        if (undefined === this.o) return 'undefined';
        return JSON.stringify(this.o);
    }

    get({k}, args, context, info) {
        // NOTICE: this would be perfect if an error didn't abort the query
        //     returning zero results, instead of partial results
        // if (undefined === this.o[k]) {
        //     throw Error(`key ${k} was undefined`);
        // }
        return new SchemalessDoc(this.o[k]);
    }
}

const root = {
    // authenticate
    auth: function ({ name, phrase }, args, context, info) {
        // throw Error(`whats up?`);
        return new SchemalessDoc({ _id: 'abcd-efgh-hij', a: { b: { c: 3 }}});
    },
    deauth(obj, args, context, info) {
        debugger;
    },

    // crud for all models
    create(obj, args, context, info) {
        debugger;
    },
    update(obj, args, context, info) {
        debugger;
    },
    delete(obj, args, context, info) {
        debugger;
    },
};

const query = async s =>
    graphql(schema, s, root);

describe('graphql', () => {
    it('works', async () => {
        const output = await query(`
        mutation {
            auth(
                name: "mike",
                phrase: "turkey"
            ) {
                _id,
                a: get(k:"a") { 
                    b: get(k:"b") {
                        x: get(k:"x") {
                            json
                        },                        
                        c: get(k:"c") {
                            json
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        `);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(output)); // => 
            // {"data":{"auth":{"_id":"abcd-efgh-hij","a":{"b":{"x":{"json":"undefined"},"c":{"json":"\"hamster\""}}}}}}
        debugger;
    });
});

// obviously this method requires you to both
// insert data as a JSON string,
// and parse JSON at the very end
// but you can still reduce keys server-side using your get() query

// honestly this is how they should have made it
// and support should be first-class
// no type validation just run it and see
// and stop recursing once you resolve the first null
// and for parallel resolves with some null just return the partial results you have
// and include errors[] for the keys which were undefined

// one downside without that first-class support is 
// the json comes back double-escaped as json string inside json.

// the other downside is that it removes the ability to
// do dynamic lookups on foreign key references
// unless you define a specific string or data type for that.
// ie. if it finds a string 'TypeName#abcd-defgh' then it 
// could go lookup and attach that document
```

see also (other ways to do it):

(i like this one because it provides typed getters instead of everything-as-a-string)

http://blog.riand.com/2017/03/schemaless-graphql.html

https://blog.hasura.io/working-with-schemaless-data-with-graphql-on-postgres-574a1ee2e87f/

https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/403

**UPDATE**:

I eventually went with a greatly simplified from-scratch implementation. Sharing in the hope that others may take gratuitous inspiration:

https://gist.github.com/ancmikesmullin/526b64b262561fb4ca1be824c2faec7f#file-test-sgql-alpha2-js-L63-L67

Comment: I wish your gist link still worked! I'd love to see what you ended up doing, because I'm considering something similar.